# How to pass filters in with Gibbon Export API call for Mailchimp

Tags: ruby, mailchimp, gibbon

I am working on retrieving subscriber activity from Mailchimp using Gibbon and the campaignSubscriberActivity method of the Export API. I am using Ruby 2.1.2 and Gibbon 1.1.3.

I setup Gibbon::Export

```
@gibbon_export = Gibbon::Export.new(@api_key)
```

Then have a method that loops over a set of Mailchimp campaign IDs and retrieves the activity for each.

This is the code referenced by the following error.

```
  activities = @gibbon_export.campaignSubscriberActivity({
    :apikey => @api_key,
    :id => campaign['campaign_id'], 
    :since =>  "2014-10-17 00:00:00"
  })
```

This is the error I get:

```
/Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.10.1/lib/multi_json/adapter.rb:19:in `load': JSON::ParserError (MultiJson::ParseError)
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/multi_json-1.10.1/lib/multi_json.rb:119:in `load'
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gibbon-1.1.3/lib/gibbon/export.rb:26:in `call'
    from /Users/pierce/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/gibbon-1.1.3/lib/gibbon/export.rb:55:in `method_missing'
    from mc_get_campaign_subscriber_activity.rb:63:in `block in retrieve_campaign_subscriber_activity_from_mc'
```

Mailchimp API support suggested that the :since parameter is not formatted correctly and I need to encode the space in the date with %20. However, when I add the %20 so the :since parameter is "2014-10-17%2000:00:00" I still get the same error.

Is there any formatting changes I need to make? Also, how can I get the complete URL that is being sent to Mailchimp so I can see the final values?

Comment: hi there - can I see an activities response with no `since` field?  I need to see how mailchimp has encoded their time.

Comment: Here is a single activity that was returned. {\"action\":\"open\",\"timestamp\":\"2014-07-29 16:51:26\",\"url\":null,\"ip\":\"0.0.0.0\"}

Comment: any chance of not using Gibbon?  Their source code includes `method_missing` which to be frank is not ideal for an external API.  I've got your call working using mailchimp's official ruby wrapper and happy to answer with that if you want.

Comment: @Anthony I don't need to use Gibbon. I have used it for the rest of the mailchimp integrations I have used. I'm happy to try your solution. Getting it to work is more important.

Comment: @Anthony do you have a solution to propose? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the gem:

`m = Mailchimp::API.new(api_key_here)`

First you'll need your campaign ID's and if you don't have those you can run:

`m.lists.list` that will give you all your campaigns and you can get your id(s) accordingly.

Loop over your campaigns and use this:

```
m.lists.activity('campaign_id').select { |i| i["day"] == "2014-09-30" }
```

That will give you the records you need based on the date match in `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, @analyticsPierce is using `gibbon` for the `Mailchimp` api, not the `Mailchimp` ruby api gem.

Comment: Check out the comments below the initial post @PeteyT .

Comment: @Anthony So the 'activity' method gives me totals for that campaign. Not the same as the campaignSubscriberActivity from the Export API which gives click detail for each subscriber. Also, this gives me just the totals for that one day, not all results since that day. I only had time to do a quick overview before the time to accept ran out. I hope you can follow up with some more detail.

Comment: @analyticsPierce have you looked at [#member_activity](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby/src/fc745199610bc00ecb42388a241c8018e20cc4a1/lib/mailchimp/api.rb?at=master#cl-842) ?

Comment: @Anthony #member_activity is to retrieve activity for a single member. It is not the same as campaignSubscriberActivity which gives you all the activity for a single campaign.

Comment: @Anthony from the mailchimp api source on bitbucket it looks like they don't have anything made to support the Export API.

Comment: hrm - I apologize @analyticsPierce , let me see if I can get this working with Gibbon or something custom.

Comment: @Anthony Gibbon just released a new version that was supposed to fix a JSON parsing error. might be related to the problem I had. I am testing that update now.

Comment: @Anthony The Gibbon update fixed the problem. That library works for the Export API now.

Comment: thats great @analyticsPierce - please feel free to edit my answer so other users can benefit.